# How to change value of other spinners on the basis of selection of of the first spinner?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I am trying to change the value of the course name and course section on the selection of the value from the program name. when I select the program name the course name of the selected program displayed in the course name spinner And at the same time the course section spinner populates with the section of the selected course name. but when I change the program name the course name spinner also updates itself but the course section spinner did not update itself with the section of the by-default selected course until or unless I select any other value from the course name.

Below is the picture for xml of activity:

[picture for xml of activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOs7I.png)

Below is my firebase database structure:

```
Courses Details" : {
    "Bs-BBA" : {
      "-MVuhKkfxjHkZmTfsITM" : {
        "Economics" : {
          "courseName" : "Economics",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Tuesday",
          "endingTime" : "1:30Pm",
          "programName" : "Bs-BBA",
          "startingTime" : "12:00Pm"
        }
      },
      "-MWwNgr6yT8b0ARo86DN" : {
        "Human resource Management" : {
          "courseName" : "Human resource Management",
          "courseSection" : "G",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "7:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bs-BBA",
          "startingTime" : "6:00AM"
        }
      }
    },
    "Bscs" : {
      "-MVWl1uq9fA4AlYRfMIv" : {
        "Data structure" : {
          "courseName" : "Data structure",
          "courseSection" : "B",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Monday",
          "endingTime" : "9:30AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MVY9hGxrp8Lz4JTOefy" : {
        "OOP" : {
          "courseName" : "OOP",
          "courseSection" : "C",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "10:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MVYHM0c7cMLersoUl2i" : {
        "Marketing Fundamental" : {
          "courseName" : "Marketing Fundamental",
          "courseSection" : "D",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "11:00AM"
        }
      }
    },
    "Bsse" : {
      "-MVYHB3X_d4UozbBUDa3" : {
        "Marketing Fundamental" : {
          "courseName" : "Marketing Fundamental",
          "courseSection" : "E",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bsse",
          "startingTime" : "2:00AM"
        }
      }
    },
    "Mscs" : {
      "-MWg6Ua5E9x9dSJ31552" : {
        "MoT" : {
          "courseName" : "MoT",
          "courseSection" : "F",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Wednesday",
          "endingTime" : "10:00AM",
          "programName" : "Mscs",
          "startingTime" : "3:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MWrD3bp9t2kt4Ze40-D" : {
        "Advance Data Structure" : {
          "courseName" : "Advance Data Structure",
          "courseSection" : "G",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "1:00Pm",
          "programName" : "Mscs",
          "startingTime" : "5:00AM"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

And this is my java code for population and selecting spinner values:

```
// populating spinner for Course program

        spinnerForProgramName = findViewById(R.id.course_program);

        spinnerForProgramNameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerForProgramNameArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssignCoursesToFaculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerForProgramNameArrayList);
        spinnerForProgramName.setAdapter(spinnerForProgramNameArrayAdapter);

        getDataIntoSpinnerForProgramNameFromFirebase();


        // Populating spinner for Course Name

        spinnerForCourseName = findViewById(R.id.course_name) ;

        spinnerForCourseNameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerForCourseNameArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssignCoursesToFaculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerForCourseNameArrayList);
        spinnerForCourseName.setAdapter(spinnerForCourseNameArrayAdapter);


        spinnerForProgramName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                getDataIntoSpinnerCourseName();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }

        });


        // Populating spinner For Course Sec

        spinnerForCourseSection = findViewById(R.id.course_sec) ;

        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssignCoursesToFaculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerForCourseSecArrayList);
        spinnerForCourseSection.setAdapter(spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter);


        // Populating spinner For Course Starting Time

        spinnerForCourseStartingTime = findViewById(R.id.course_start_time) ;

        spinnerForCourseStartingTimeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerForCourseStartingTImeArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssignCoursesToFaculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerForCourseStartingTimeArrayList);
        spinnerForCourseStartingTime.setAdapter(spinnerForCourseStartingTImeArrayAdapter);


        spinnerForCourseName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                getDataIntoSpinnerCourseSec();

                //getDataIntoSpinnerStartingTime();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }

        });



public void getDataIntoSpinnerForProgramNameFromFirebase()
    {

        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses Details");

        listener = dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {

                spinnerForProgramNameArrayList.clear();

                for( DataSnapshot courseDetails:snapshot.getChildren() )
                {

                    String programAndDepartmentNameKey = courseDetails.getKey();
                    spinnerForProgramNameArrayList.add(programAndDepartmentNameKey);

                }

                spinnerForProgramNameArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {



            }
        });

    }

    public void getDataIntoSpinnerCourseName()
    {

        String selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName = spinnerForProgramName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;

        ValueEventListener listener;

        final DatabaseReference rootRef;
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses Details");

        listener = rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {

                if( snapshot.child(selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName).exists() )
                {

                    spinnerForCourseNameArrayList.clear();

                    for( DataSnapshot programNameKey: snapshot.child(selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName).getChildren() )
                    {

                        for( DataSnapshot courseNameKey : programNameKey.getChildren() )
                        {

                            String courseName = courseNameKey.getKey() ;

                            spinnerForCourseNameArrayList.add(courseName);

                        }

                    }

                    spinnerForCourseNameArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void getDataIntoSpinnerCourseSec()
    {

        String selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName = spinnerForProgramName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;
        String selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName = spinnerForCourseName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;

        ValueEventListener listener;

        final DatabaseReference rootRef;
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses Details");

        listener = rootRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {

                spinnerForCourseSecArrayList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot programNameKey : snapshot.child(selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName).getChildren())
                {

                    for (DataSnapshot randomIdKey : programNameKey.getChildren())
                    {

                        String courseName = randomIdKey.getKey();

                        if( randomIdKey.child(courseName).getKey().equals(selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName) )
                        {

                            for (DataSnapshot courseNameKey : randomIdKey.getChildren())
                            {

                                String courseNameDetail = courseNameKey.getKey();

                                if ( courseNameKey.child(courseNameDetail).getKey().equals("courseSection") )
                                {

                                    spinnerForCourseSecArrayList.add(courseNameKey.getValue().toString());

                                }

                            }

                        }


                    }

                }

                spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {

            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you will get the section data when the course name will be selected as
`getDataIntoSpinnerCourseSec()` is written inside `onItemSelected` of `spinnerForCourseName` .

To fix it you can move your `getDataIntoSpinnerCourseSec()` inside `onItemSelected` of `spinnerForProgramName`

```
spinnerForProgramName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                getDataIntoSpinnerCourseName();
                getDataIntoSpinnerCourseSec();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }

        });
```

Comment: i tried it in that way too but my activity crashes when i do that

Answer (score 0):

Look at below example I have made just to resolve your issue. For ease of understanding I am not using your Firebase data instead I have created dummy data. I hope you can get clue to solve your problem from below example.

```
public class MultiSpinnerTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

interface CommonItem{
    String getName();
    List<CommonItem> getList();
}
private class Item implements CommonItem{
    String itemName;
    Item(String itemName){
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CommonItem> getList() {
        return null;
    }
}
private class SubCategory implements CommonItem{
    String subCategoryName;
    List<CommonItem> items;
    SubCategory(String subCategoryName, List<CommonItem> itemList){
        this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
        this.items = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return subCategoryName;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CommonItem> getList() {
        return items;
    }
}
private class Category implements CommonItem{
    String categoryName;
    List<CommonItem> subCategories;
    Category(String categoryName, List<CommonItem> subCategoryList){
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.subCategories = subCategoryList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CommonItem> getList() {
        return subCategories;
    }
}
ArrayList<CommonItem> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<CommonItem> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<CommonItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;
ArrayAdapter spinner1Adapter,spinner2Adapter,spinner3Adapter;
int currentCategory = 0, currentSubCategory = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_spinner_test);
    spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_1);
    spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_2);
    spinner3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_3);

    // Just creating sample nested list. Category contains SubCategory, SubCategory contains Item.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        subCategories = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++){
                items.add(new Item("Item"+i+j+m));
            }
            subCategories.add(new SubCategory("Sub Category"+i+ j,items));
        }
        categoryArrayList.add(new Category("Category "+i,subCategories));
    }

    //spinner1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categoryArrayList);
    spinner1Adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, categoryArrayList);
    spinner1.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            resetSpinner2(categoryArrayList.get(position).getList());
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
    });
    spinner1.setSelection(0);
}
private void resetSpinner2(List<CommonItem> subCategories){
    //spinner2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, subCategories);
    spinner2Adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, subCategories);
    spinner2.setAdapter(spinner2Adapter);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            resetSpinner3(subCategories.get(position).getList());
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
    });
    spinner2.setSelection(0);
}
private void resetSpinner3(List<CommonItem> itemList){
    //spinner3Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemList);
    spinner3Adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, itemList);
    spinner3.setAdapter(spinner3Adapter);

    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.d("Tag==>>","Selected Item = "+itemList.get(position).getName());
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
    });
    spinner3.setSelection(0);
}
class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CommonItem> {
    Context context;
    List<CommonItem> itemList;
    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<CommonItem> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = objects;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
        return createView(position,view,viewGroup);
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, @NotNull ViewGroup viewGroup){
        return createView(position,view,viewGroup);
    }

    private View createView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item_view,viewGroup,false);
        TextView textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_tv);
        textView.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        return itemView;
    }
}
}
```

activity_multi_spinner_test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MultiSpinnerTestActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_1"/>
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_2"/>
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

custom_spinner_item_view.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/spinner_item_tv"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
android:padding="5dp">
```